# Transfer large file from remote server to remote workstation

Tags: windows, file-transfer, data-transfer

I have a large file on one of our servers that I need to get onto someones workstation.

If (on my own workstation) I open the server folder and also open another window with the admin share (c$) of the workstation, then drag the file from the server folder to the workstation admin share, is this file going via my workstation first?

If so, this is not optimal and I need a good method to do file transfers like this remotely without having to remote desktop onto their machine.

The server and their workstation are relatively close, that is why I want the transfer to go straight from server to their workstation. 
My workstation is far away and sending files from my workstation is slow so not really an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is a USB pendrive or a DVD not an option here?

Comment: There is a great physical distance unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you load both remote sources from your local workstation, the traffic for the transfer will go via your local workstation.

You have a few options:

- Physical transfer: copy the data to a physical device, move the device, copy the data back
- Copy the data on one of the devices, remotely to the other: Can you RDP/VNC/Remote Desktop of some sort onto one of the devices? If so, then simply open the share from one remote device, directly copying it onto the other.
- Setup something like DFS which will 'sync' the files between the two servers. (If you can do this however, you can likely do the option above this which will be easier for a 'one off' transfer).

Comment: Yes, I can RDP to server and send from there to workstation. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) - Glad it helped -- if it was linux, there's plenty of more 'fun' ways but unfortunately for windows it's very limited in this area.